# How to check if an object is of a custom type imported from a different file

Tags: python

I have a python program with multiple files and import some classes from one file into another. The issue is when I import the class from another file, the object type is not considered `<filename.customtype>` instead of just `<customtype>`. This makes it difficult when I want to check if an object is of an instance of that type.

I have attached a MWE of this issue. The first block of code of from the file that defines the custom class and the second block of code is the file that imports the custom class.

Custom class file:

```
import numpy as np

class Coordinates:
    def __init__( self, n ):
        self.x = np.zeros(n)
        self.y = np.zeros(n)
        self.z = np.zeros(n)

def magnitude( p = None ):
    if p is not None:
        # Check if p is of class coordinates
        print(type(p))
        if type(p) is Coordinates:
            return np.sqrt( p.x**2 + p.y**2 + p.z**2 )
        else:
            return
```

The main script file that imports the custom class:

```
from coordinates import Coordinates, magnitude

c = Coordinates(2)

m = magnitude(c)
```

The issue is when I call `magnitude` the I do not get the desired `return` value because the line `if type(p) is Coordinates` does not return true, because the object now has the type `<filename.Coordinates>`.

I am not sure how I can include the appropriate filename in the `if type(p) is Coordinates` line of what the best way to deal with this issue is.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It works properly. Did you actually try `print(m)`? I get `[0. 0.]`, which is the expected result. Please make a [mre] including expected output and actual output, as well as removing the dependency on NumPy, since it's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: `<filename.Coordinates>` is just the string representation you are printing. It is actually the `Coordinates` class, so your check will be `True`.

Comment: I see, thanks. I assumed I had to match the string representation, but I should have just checked if I actually go the result I desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if an object is an instance of a dedicated class, use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```py
def magnitude( p = None ):
    if p is not None:
        # Check if p is of class coordinates
        if isinstance(p, Coordinates):
            return np.sqrt( p.x**2 + p.y**2 + p.z**2 )
        else:
            return
```

[`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is only used to get the type of an object, but should not be used for checks.

No matter if you use `type` or `isinstance`, your code looks OK and should return the the calculated values.

```
In [1]: c = Contract()

In [2]: print(type(c))
<class 'contracts.models.Contract'>

In [3]: type(c) == Contract
Out[3]: True

In [4]: type(c) is Contract
Out[4]: True

In [5]: isinstance(c, Contract)
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: This is best practice, but it doesn't actually answer the question. OP's saying `type(p) is Coordinates` is returning `False`, but it's actually not. I think they're confused.

Comment: On second thought, it's perfectly valid to use `type(obj) is ...` when you need to match the class *but not subclasses*. Although I can't think of an example of the top of my head, and it's not clear if that's what OP wants.

Comment: @wjandrea you're right. You can use either `type` or `isinstance` in case of the posted question.